# How to convert memory element to string in python?

Tags: python, string, memory, call, odoo

I want to view the string representation of memory element of the following code:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L233

When i print "keep", it gives **"odoo.addons.website.controllers.main.QueryURL object at 0xb1438fac".**

How actually i can convert it into string OR human readable format?

The original code of QueryURL class is in below link:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L233

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source for QueryURL](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/website/controllers/main.py#L33), it seems to me that you have to call the url in order to have string representation. Try:

```
print(keep())
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have notices from the output you are getting, `keep` is an object of type `QueryURL`. Since, it is a custom object made from an already defined class, it lacks the `__repr__()` or the `__str__()` methods. These methods return a string which represents the data stored in the custom class. If these methods are missing from your class, the `print` function prints the address of where the object is being stored in the memory.

The already existing classes, like `int` or `str` have their `__repr__()` already defined. Hence, whenever you print an `int` object, you view it's value, and not address.

To resolve this issue you can approach two methods:

1. All you have to define is a custom method which prints the required data from the object to the console (or wherever). You can either define a function out of the class, which returns the required string (string containing the data of the object, you want), and call that function inside print, like: `print(functionWhichReturnsStringOfObject(Object))`,
2. Or just edit the class definition, and add `__repr__()` method to it, which does the same work as the function above. After doing this, you just have to `print(object)`